# Are there any particular properties of a matrix that determine it's nullity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, I've seen a 2x3 matrix whose null space has a basis of two vectors; the null space is a plane. I've also seen a 3x4 matrix whose null space has a basis of only one vectors; a line.

Is there some common property that will allow you correctly predict a matrix's nullity without having to solve the homogenous equation using its rows every time?

Comment: Rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: It's rank, with the rank-nullity formula. However it still requires some computations.